# Law of total probability Random Walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I am trying to show that if we let $\{Z_{n},n\geq 1\}$ independent and identically distributed random variables with $P\left[Z_{1}=1 \right]=p=1-P\left[Z_{1}=0\right]$. Let $T_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}Z_{j}$ be a random walk on $\{0,1,2,..\}$ that can either make one step to the right or stay in its current state and that it starts at state 0. Then, I am trying to show that for $n\geq 0$ and $1\geq j \geq n+1$, $P[T_{n+1}=j]=pP[T_{n}=j-1]+(1-p)P[T_{n}=j]$.

I already show this using Mathematical Induction but I want to do this using the law of total probability. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(T_{n+1}=j)= P(T_{n+1}=j|Z_1=1)P(Z_1=1)+P(T_{n+1}=j|Z_1=0)P(Z_1=0)$$ $$=pP(T_n=j-1)+(1-p)P(T_n=j)$$ where the last step follows from the fact that the sequences  $( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Z_k)$ and $( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Z_{k+1})$ have the same distribution (because $(Z_j)$ is i.i.d.).

Comment: How you get this part in the first line $P(T_{n+1}=j|Z_1=-1)P(Z_1=-1)$?

Comment: @AlexisSandoval Sorry. I wrote $Z_1=-1$ instead of $Z_1=0$. (I was thinking of  asymmetric random walk).

Comment: Also, why  $P(T_{n+1}=j|Z_1=1)=P(T_n=j-1)$ and $P(T_{n+1}=j|Z_1=0)=P(T_n=j)$?

Comment: That is where you need that fact that $(Z_1,Z_2,...)$ and $(Z_2,Z_3,...)$ have identical properties. For a rigorous proof you have to know how sequences of random variable induce an infinite dimensional distribution on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$. If you are not familiar with this you can take it intuitively. @AlexisSandoval

Comment: Thank you so much!